# vtg-plugin dependencies not met

Tags: compiling, dependencies, vala, pkg-config

I am trying to compile the vtg-plugin from source however I am getting the error "vtg-dependencies not met" which complains about libpeas and gedit.

The version of gedit it is asking for is 2.91.0, while the version of libpeas it wants is 0.7.4.

Running

`pkg-config --modversion gedit-2.20` returns 2.30.4

`pkg-config --modversion libpeas-1.0` returns 0.7.3

My problem is running apt-get for the latest versions (`apt-get update and apt-get upgrade`)tells me *I am* using the latest version

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apt-get is telling you that you are using the latest version *available for your version of Ubuntu*.  That doesn't mean there aren't newer versions available in a newer (perhaps unstable) version of Ubuntu.

You have a few options:

1. Upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu, that includes gedit 2.91.0 and libpeas 0.7.4
2. See if the [Ubuntu Backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) archive has gedit 2.9.10 and libpeas 0.7.4 built for your version of Ubuntu
3. Compile and install the newer versions of gedit and libpeas from the newer version of Ubuntu, leaving everything else alone.  This option often leads to *more* unmet build dependencies, which can turn into a complicated mess.  This is why Backports is so nice--it means someone else has already done that work for you.
4. Find someone who has built vtg-plugin for your version of Ubuntu (so it works with the versions of gedit and lipeas you already have)
5. Find an older version of vtg-plugin that doesn't require the newer dependencies.

Comment: Good luck... and BTW, which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using 11.04